# What does `_ -> ()` mean in OCaml function?

Tags: function, syntax, compiler-construction, ocaml, ocamlyacc

I'm looking at this chun of code (the first 2 lines are pseudo code for context)

```
typ = Void | Bool | Int
type bind = typ * string 

let check_binds (kind : string) (binds : bind list) =
    List.iter (function
    (Void, b) -> raise (Failure ("illegal void " ^ kind ^ " " ^ b))
      | _ -> ()) binds;
```

So what I think is happening is that there is a list called `binds`, and because of `iter`, the function defined inside the parentheses after "`List.iter`" is being applied to every item in `binds`.

However I'm confused about the function itself. Here's my attempt at trying to write out the function individually

```
function 
(Void, b) -> raise (Failure ("illegal void " ^ kind ^ " " ^ b)
| _ -> ()
```

What does `_ -> ()` mean?

Comment: looks like `check_binds` will raise an error if there's any Void in binds, and return nothing of interest otherwise.

Comment: A couple of style notes: there is some real funkiness occurring here with indentation, and your `check_binds` function can infer the types of its arguments without the explicit type annotations. You may wish to review the [OCaml Programming Guidelines](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/guidelines.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an anonymous function definition using pattern-matching with 2 clauses:

- 1st one covers the case `(Void, b)`
- 2nd one covers "everything else": `_` in a pattern matching is a catch-all branch that matches anything.

And when the latter branch is matched in your snippet the function will  just return `()` - which is the only possible value of type `unit`.

So this lambda function is a kind of validator that raises an error if you have a value with a wrong type (Void parametrized by anything) and does nothing (returns a unit) in other cases. And honestly, this looks like a hack that tries to mitigate the sub-optimal types design - I'm quite sure we can do better and make `(Void, b)` unrepresentable state (but this is orthogonal to what was asked)...